# Unable to control what the user can see in php?

Tags: php, forms, action

I want to control what the user can see in my system. A guy told me that I should check if the user id matches with the lecturer id. The lecturer should see only their own data not any other's lecturer. I tried but now it doesn't work.

I also get these errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: userID in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\statistics\lecturer.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: lecID in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\statistics\lecturer.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_fecth_row() in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\statistics\lecturer.php on line 24

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841797/how-can-i-make-the-user-evaluation-scores-private-in-php

I also tested the query and I got:

[image]

I think it is a little bit weird. I have on tables users with userid,username and type and a lecturer table with lecturer id and lecturer name.

```
 include 'connect.php';

   $userID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userID']);
   $lecID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lecID']);
   $year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']);
   $lecturer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lecturer']); // Don't forget to handle the SQL Injections ...
   $years     = array(
      2005,
      2006,
      2007
   );
  $lecturers = array(
     'dimopoulos',
     'lagkas',
     'kehagias',
     'chrysochoou'
  );

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       if($userID==$lecID){
         $check=("SELECT users.uid,lecturer.lec_id FROM users,lecturer");
          $row=mysql_fecth_row($check);

        if($row[0]==$lecturer){

            if (in_array($lecturer, $lecturers) && in_array($year, $years)) {

                 $sql = "SELECT unit_name,a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,lavg,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3 FROM $lecturer WHERE year=$year";
               $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }

        else {
            echo "No data found";
        }


      }
    }
 }


    ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statistics/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="container">
      <table id="table" width="900" border="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
    <td>Unit Name</td>
    <td>A1 </td>
    <td>A2 </td>
    <td>A3 </td>
    <td>L1 </td>
    <td>L2 </td>
    <td>L3 </td>
    <td>L4 </td>
    <td>L5 </td>
    <td>L6 </td>
    <td>L7 </td>
    <td>LAVG </td>
    <td>R1 </td>
    <td>R2 </td>
    <td>U1 </td>
    <td>U2 </td>
    <td>U3 </td>


</tr>

<?php
    while($unit=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['unit_name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['a3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l3']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l4']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l5']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l6']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['l7']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['lavg']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['r1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['r2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u2']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$unit['u3']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";    
    }
?>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use php Session to store user information after login and then show/hide data based on them.

See documentation from here-
[PHP SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: should I create a table for logged in users? And which session should I use?

Comment: table in the database?

Comment: @ Khairul Islam I googled "use php Session to store user information after login", I now see what you meant !!!

Comment: my pleasure :) finally you understood what i actually meant.

Comment: I don't know to do it. But I thought something like storing the username and user id in terms of session after login. Therefore, when a lectruer user goes to their page to select a lecturer name and a year I should store in session the selected name so to match it with the username?

Comment: yeah, something like this. when a user log in to your site put the user id or any login information in session and when a user/lecturer select a name then match the selected item's id/name with the item that you have in your session, if both are matched then show else hide.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing (as your error message suggests) `mysql_fecth_row` is not a PHP function. There's a typo there - it should be `mysql_fetch_row`.